# Grid with different height images

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to create a grid layout for my portfolio site. I'm having trouble with getting it to work online. When I try a preview in dreamweaver it look just fine, but when uploaded it's all messed up.. Please help

http://www.kaspervanvliet.nl/index.html

HTML:

```
<div id="images-containter">
      <div class="col">
         <img src="images/k_Web-03.jpg">
            <img src="images/curriculum_new.jpg">
                <img src="images/Finnley's_2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/Justme_1.jpg">
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.images-containter {
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

.images-containter img{
width: 350px;
height: auto;
background: #fffff;
padding: 0px;
margin: 15px;
border: none;
}

.col {
width: 350px;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 15px;
vertical-align: top;
align: center;
}
```

Comment: You're not giving enough information.
We can't help you if you don't say your current code and what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: How is it supposed to look?

Comment: @FC' Sorry, even trying to put in the code question was a hassle :p

Comment: @Tdelang: The look which I am aiming for is a centered single page website, with a logo on top and 3 columns with different height images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width and height on your image tags. I assume you want it to all look the same cross browser. That would be the best bet.

Your code: **my changes**

```
<div class="col">
         <img src="images/k_Web-03.jpg" **height="100" width="75"**>
            <img src="images/curriculum_new.jpg"  **height="100" width="75"**>
                <img src="images/Finnley's_2.jpg"  **height="100" width="75"**>
                    <img src="images/Justme_1.jpg"  **height="100" width="75"**>
            </div>

        etc...
```

This takes some planning on your part, but you could simply allow them to click the image and see a full view. Otherwise, you're going to have different images with different aspect ratios and it will never look as good as you want it to.

Also, please don't structure your site with tables unless you're going to be using tabular data. It's a pain to edit in the long run.

EDIT****

The below html/css will give you the desired result. There are 4 divs with the class of "cols" those 4 divs are set up to be 4 columns. The images inside the div will stack, evenly spaced above and below. Also, the height will automatically adjust based on the width being constrained to 230px.

Let me know if you need anything else.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrap{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.cols{
    width:230px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}

.cols img{
    width:230px;
    display:block;
    margin:5px 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cols">
        <img src="images/k_Web-01.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-02.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-03.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        <img src="images/k_Web-04.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-05.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-06.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        <img src="images/k_Web-07.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-08.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-09.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cols">
        <img src="images/k_Web-10.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-11.jpg">
        <img src="images/k_Web-12.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack, I'm very new to making websites.. The point is that I don't want the images to have the same height. Eventually I want 3 columns center with a logo in the header. I've deleted the table part in the code. Positioning is best in CSS right?

Comment: That is correct. So from your statement, you want to have the same width, but different heights?

Comment: I did NOT include the header code for your logo, you will need to add that yourself.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.. I can't find a good way to center the header and columns. I've tried a couple of possibilities but none of them are working..

Comment: the code I gave you should center the columns on its own. Create a div outside the div with the class of wrapper and give it the class of logo. - the css would be .logo{height:height; width:width; margin:10px auto;} - the height and width will be the height and width on the logo.

Comment: I was messing with the width of the columns, thats why it wouldn't work.. Thanks a lot! Code looks a lot cleaner also! haha

Comment: One last thing: Do you know how I can make the width responsive? I was trying with max-width but it doesn't work well for the images and margins. Thanks

Comment: I do, but are you wanting me to code your whole site? I like helping, but if you want to learn, you can youtube tuts or subscribe to Lynda.com. (there is a fee for Lynda.com)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not trying to make you write my code at all.. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Email me, or contact me through my website: jvincilione[@]lucienconsulting.com, http://lucienconsulting.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css to set the heights and widths one time. Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="port"><img src="images/..."></img></div>
  <div class="land"><img src="images/..."></img></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img_container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color:grey;
}
.port {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
.land {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

That's better, because you cut the style from code.